# binary representation of char, int and float

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binary(char* a){
        int bit_index = (sizeof(*a) * 8 - 1);
        int i;
        printf("\n bit_index : %d *a : %c \n",bit_index,*a);
        for(i = 0; i < bit_index; i++){
                printf("%d",(*a & (1 << i)));
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
int main(){
        char a = 'a';
        int b = 67;
        float c = 3.14;
        binary(&a);
        return 0;
}
```

I was converting a char into binary representation. 
The above program gives a junk o/p as,

```
bit_index : 7 *a : a 
100003264
```

I wanted the above program to take input of any type variable to convert into a binary representation.

So I used void* instead of char* as an argument for the func binary(void *). But I got an error when used so as,

```
binary.c: In function ‘binary’:
binary.c:17:50: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
binary.c:17:2: error: invalid use of void expression
binary.c:19:16: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
binary.c:19:3: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Is there a way to create a function to input any type of variable and to putput its binary representation.

Comment: Just add a `size` argument to your existing function.

Comment: `char` is not always 8 bits. And `sizeof(char)` is **always** 1 by standard, so `sizeof(*a)*8` should be `1*CHAR_BIT`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dereference a void* pointer. Instead, to get the binary representation, take a (the parameter of binary) as void* and cast it to char* to be able to display it byte by byte.

You should also take a size parameter, as various data types has various sizes. So, a call to binary should be something like `binary(&a, sizeof(a))`

Comment: Actually, dereferencing a pointer to void is not illegal per se but usage of void expression is illegal. C99 6.3.2.2: "The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an expression.". This is also what compiler says - it only gives you warning when you dereference a pointer to void but yields an error when you try to use void expression.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to print either a '1' or a '0', not the result of `(*a & (1 << i))`

   `printf("%d",(*a & (1 << i)) != 0);`

   (or `printf("%d",!!(*a & (1 << i)));`)
2. Use an `unsigned char` when you want to access the underlying bits, there's no reason to have to deal with
   a potential sign bit of a `char`, and you should pass in the size of the type you're accessing (as the size of  char is always 1, your `sizeof *a` is always 1., i.e. the prototype should be

   `int binary(void* a_, size_t len) {
        unsigned char *a = a_; //use a here to access the bits.`

   and you'd call it as

   `binary(&b, sizeof *b);`
3. You might want to print the most significant bit first instead of the least significant bit first.